# Changing DOM <input> values with a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So all I want to do is use a loop to set the value attribute in this code from my DOM to 0.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Pn_87001_qty" id="Pn_87001_qty" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="Pn_87001_qty" id="Pn_87002_qty" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="Pn_87001_qty" id="Pn_87003_qty" value="1" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="Pn_87001_qty" id="Pn_87004_qty" value="1" />
```

I have this function that creates an array with all of the  id's in it.

```
function testing02() {
    var eles = [];
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Pn_"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name.indexOf('#Pn_') == 0) {
            eles.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(inputs.length); 
}
```

And I can change the value of individual value attributes with this code:

```
test01 = document.getElementById('Pn_87001_qty');
test01.setAttribute("value", "1000");
```

That being said, I can not figure out a way to make a loop that sets the value attribute based on the ID's from my input array. Nor can I figure out a way to make the loop above fill the input array with the entire input element so that I can write a second loop to change the values. I've tried using .getElementsByName, .getElementsByClass as well as document.querySelector.

I'm stuck and new to javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can do Jquery or Javascript

Comment: Maybe you could use a foreach loop.

Comment: Better set the `value` property instead of the `value` attribute.

Comment: You wrote `.indexOf('#Pn_')`. Don't you mean `.indexOf('Pn_')`, without the sharp sign?

Comment: Andre Yes I did, sorry.

Comment: @Oriol I tried setting the value property with .val(0) and it comes back NaN.

Comment: @dm8021122 You can use `.val(0)` or `.prop('value', 0)` with jQuery objects. With the real html elements, use `.value = 0`.

Comment: Why are you using a changing (though predictable) `id` instead of the native `getElementsByName('Pn_87001_qty')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have tagged this question with jQuery, I assume a jQuery answer will suffice. To that end, you don't need a loop and can simply use:

```
$('[id^="Pn_"]').val(0);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zaqhcs6/)

You could optimise this further by giving the hidden elements a common class attribute and changing the selector to use that.

Comment: I tried that command 2 or 3 times and could not get it to return anything but NaN... Until now, and I think I just realized what I was doing wrong in checking that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One question, what are the benefits of using a common class over the id? From the reading I've been doing it seems like using the id is usually the best way to go.

Comment: The id selector is the fastest, eg. `#myElement`, but this can only select a single element. Your selector is the 'attribute begins with' version, which is very slow in comparison - even when selecting the `id` attribute. A class selector will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#` prefix from your name.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Pn_"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].name.indexOf('Pn_') == 0) {
        inputs[i].value = 0;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b3na8tqf/)

Answer (score 0):

To convert the `NodeList` to an array, you can use:

- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop

  ```js
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Pn_"]'),
      eles = Array(inputs.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      eles[i] = inputs[i];
  }
  ```
- [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

  ```js
  var eles = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Pn_"]'));
  ```
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) (EcmaScript 6, [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill))

  ```js
  var eles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Pn_"]'));
  ```

To set the value of all them to `'0'`, you can use:

- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop

  ```js
  // Note you don't have to convert `inputs` to array
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      inputs[i].value = '0';
  }
  ```
- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (EcmaScript 5, [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill))

  ```js
  // Note you must convert `inputs` to array
  eles.forEach(function(el) {
      el.value = '0';
  });
  ```
- `for...of` loop (EcmaScript 6)

  ```js
  // Note you don't have to convert `inputs` to array
  for(var el of inputs) {
      el.value = 0;
  }
  ```